Multipeer Connectivity: stream callback function of StreamDelegate only called twice
I am trying to send a series of numbers using a stream through Multipeer Connectivity. But the callback function of StreamDelegate is only called twice.
    func startAngleDataStream(){
        print("Starting stream")
        guard iPadPeerID != nil else { return }
        do{
            if self.outputStream != nil{
                self.outputStream!.close()
            }
            self.outputStream = try peerSession.startStream(withName: "myStream", toPeer: iPadPeerID!)
        } catch {
            print("Error starting stream")
            return
        }
        guard self.outputStream != nil else { return }
        
        self.outputStream!.delegate = self
        self.outputStream!.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .default)
        self.outputStream!.open()
    }

The function above is called when the connection to the receiver is established.
    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        if state == .connected {
            self.startAngleDataStream()
        }
    }

This is the stream function.
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        guard shouldWriteOrientation else { return }
        switch eventCode {
        case .hasSpaceAvailable:
            guard let outputStream = aStream as? OutputStream else { return }
            var data = Data()
            data.append(Data(bytes: &calculatedOrientation.x, count: MemoryLayout<Double>.size))
            data.append(Data(bytes: &calculatedOrientation.y, count: MemoryLayout<Double>.size))
            let _ = data.withUnsafeBytes {
                outputStream.write(($0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: Double.self))!, maxLength: data.count)
            }
            shouldWriteOrientation = false
        default:
            break
        }
    }

I have checked the status of the stream, it's open when the delegate stopped responding. There are no errors in the stream. I have also tried changing the scheduled thread to .main and mode to .common. The only two times the stream function is called, the receiver received the data correctly.
